# pytest how to parameterize part of a config to each test?

Tags: python, pytest

List of test cases configs in config.yaml.

```
**config.yaml**

-id: test1
name: joker

-id: test2
name: joker

-id: test3
name: not_joker

-id: test4
name: not_joker
```

// Test code

```
test_ids, input_data = load(config.yaml)

@pytest.fixture(params=input_data, ids=test_ids
def test_setup(request):
   data=request.param
   yield data

def test_joker_names(test_setup):
   in_data=test_setup
   assert  data[name] == 'joker'
```

The above code will read config.yaml and yeild the test setup fixture for each test id in the config. But I dont't want that, I want only the first two tests where name is joker to be tested by the test **test_joker_names**. I would like to add another test to go over not_joker_names.

is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a package called [*Parametrize From File*](https://parametrize-from-file.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that makes it very easy to load test parameters from config files.  I think it'd be a good match for what you're trying to do.  Here's how you'd use it:

1. Reorganize your config file such that the top level is a dictionary mapping test names to lists of test cases:

   ```yaml
   # test_joker.yml
   test_joker_names:
     - id: test1
       name: joker

     - id: test2
       name: joker

   test_not_joker_names:
     - id: test3
       name: not_joker

     - id: test4
       name: not_joker
   ```
2. Decorate your test functions with `@parametrize_from_file`:

   ```py
   # test_joker.py
   import parametrize_from_file

   @parametrize_from_file
   def test_joker_names(name):
       assert name == 'joker'

   @parametrize_from_file
   def test_not_joker_names(name):
       assert name != 'joker'
   ```
3. Run pytest like usual.

Some comments:

- In this example the two test cases for each test are redundant, but I assume in your real application you have multiple different test cases for each test.
- This approach gets rid of the fixture entirely, which I think is a good thing.  If you actually need a fixture though, *Parameterize From File* can also parametrize fixtures.
- The `id` field in the config file is interpreted specially.  It's used as the name for the test case, and not passed to the test as a parameter.  This is described more in the docs (linked above).
- I chose the file/test names in this example so that the parameters would be found by default (i.e. without having to specify any paths).  But it's also possible to specify paths if the defaults don't work for you.

Comment: This is what I am looking for and you are right about the redundant test. I just wanted to present a problem where I read test data from single file but write separate tests for some ids.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [parametrize feature](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html) from Pytest.

You can run the test with different values at the same variables. It works like fixtures.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [("3+5", 8), ("2+4", 6), ("6*9", 42)])
def test_eval(test_input, expected):
    assert eval(test_input) == expected
```